# Why does .Count work without parentheses?

Tags: c#

If I have a list of items (e.g. `List<string> items`) in C#, I can use both:

```
items.Count()
```

and

```
items.Count
```

to get the total number of items. Is there a reason for them both being available? Why not just have the method `.Count()`?

I notice that if I filter the list (and and end up with an `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
items.Distinct().Count()
```

then `.Count()` has to be used. So why does `List<string>` allow `.Count` at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because one is an [(LINQ) extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038.aspx) on `System.Linq.Enumerable` and the other is a [property on the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/27b47ht3.aspx).

Comment: it's not property of a class it's property of an Interface `ICollection`, look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @wudzik how is it not property of a class if it's defined in the interface :) Interface is a signature not implementation. Hence it IS a property of a class it just happens to be enforced by the interface.

Comment: The property `Count` in class `List<T>` belongs to `List<T>` class. Doesn't matter if this class implements `ICollection<T>` interface, the property still belongs to the class. A interface define a contract, let me put in this words: `"If you (class) want to be marked as a my (interface) implementation, you must have these requirements."`, the requirements (in this case Count property) belong to the class.
(I'm using `List<T>` and `ICollection<T>` as example but this concept works for any case of class that implements interface.)

Comment: I guess the property is still around for backward compatibility?

Comment: @finoutlook I thought your question is very good, so I created a new topic question and already answered. See in http://stackoverflow.com/q/20551124/1233788

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi: The one situation where this would be slightly muddy would be if it were implemented explicitly, such that you couldn't refer to it directly if you had an expression of the class type rather than the interface type. Other than that, I agree completely.

Answer (score 3):

The `Count` property is not an extension, but a property of `ICollection<T>` and hence of `List<T>`.

The `Count()` function is a LINQ extension. It works by actually counting the number of items in the collection, rather than just keeping count in a field, like the `Count` property does.

**EDIT** And apparently, `Count()` will call `Count` if it is available.

Comment: The implementation of `Count()` will short-circuit on the `Count` property if the underlying type has it.

Comment: Count is from `ICollection` not `List`

Comment: @wudzik Oh right, apologies, I'll edit my comment while I still can. I was confused, standard arrays should be caught under `ICollection` anyway I think.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `List<T>` class. And thus `List<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>` you have [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension also available.

BTW `Count()` extension will simply return value of `Count` property if enumerable source implements `ICollection` interface (where this property declared):

```
ICollection is3 = source as ICollection;
if (is3 != null)
    return is3.Count;
```