# The property Count from ICollection<T> is still around for backward compatibility?

Tags: c#, linq, icollection

**Previous Context**

To understand what I'm questioning, see first the question ["Why does .Count work without parentheses?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20517988/1233788)

In that question is discussed, Why exists `Count` (property) and `Count()` (method) in classes that implements `ICollection<T>`. that question was [answered satisfactorily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518007/1233788).

But below the answer in a comment, another question was raised by [`finoutlook`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509555/finoutlook):

**The question**

The property `Count` is still around (in later .Net versions to LINq technology) for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's around so that a collection can return how many elements there are directly, without having to iterate over it.

`Enumerable.Count()` has an optimization such that if the collection implements `ICollection<T>`, it will use the property instead of iterating over the collection one element at a time, which is what you'd have to do otherwise.

It feels like a clearly useful property to me. Even if the framework were created today with LINQ in mind, I'm sure there would still be something very similar. (Admittedly I can think of various changes I'd like to see to the collection interfaces, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Although It can be truth (is still around for backward compatibility), in my point of view, backward compatibility is not the reason for this property still exists.

When you have a class that implement `ICollection<T>` in most of cases will be short way to count the elements internally (in private or protected scope of the class).

And also a collection must have knowledge of how many elements it has. As far as i am concerned, this is the main purpose of this property.